# BaseFragment with viewbinding in android

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, androidx, android-mvvm

- I have created a `BaseFragment` to inflate other fragment's layout using view binding.
- I have setup everything but getting an issue `mViewBinding` is not initialized. Guide me in the right direction.

BaseFragment.kt:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VM : ViewModel, VB : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

    protected abstract val mViewModel: VM
    protected lateinit var mViewBinding: VB

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mViewBinding = getViewBinding(inflater, container)
        return mViewBinding.root
    }

    abstract fun getViewBinding(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): VB
}
```

DemoFragment.kt:

```
class DemoFragment : BaseFragment<DemoBaseViewModel, FragmentDemoBinding>() {

    override val mViewModel: DemoBaseViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return mViewBinding.root
    }

    override fun getViewBinding(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): FragmentDemoBinding {
        return FragmentDemoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473066/removed-recycler-item-shows-up-again-after-deleting-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a design like this, your derived class `onCreateView()` should call to base class `super.onCreateView()` where the binding is initialised.

Or as Primož Ivančič points out, you don't need to override `onCreateView()` at all.

Comment: Or, in this particular case, not override `onCreateView()' at all.

Comment: Pretty dumb mistake! Thank you.